# How to insert an array to a single row in Excel using ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, arraylist, closedxml

I have an array and I need to put the elements in one row, every element of the array should be in a different cell.

```
foreach (var cell in range.Cells())
        {
            int index = 0;
            cell.Value = arrayCompany[index];
            index++;

            if (index == count)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

My array has 10 elements and the excel file generates one row but in all 10columns, cell value is the last element of the array. I want each element to be in a different column. A1=arrayCompany[0],B1=arrayCompany[1] ... 10thcolumn = arrayCompany[9]

Comment: Please detail what you want to occur, what the current code does and how i differs form what you expect. Some samples / examples would be even better.

Comment: my array has 10 elements and the excel file generates one row but in all 10columns, cell value is the last element of the array. I want each element to be in a different column. A1=arrayCompany[0],B1=arrayCompany[1] ... 10thcolumn = arrayCompany[9]

Comment: Please update your post rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
            {
                var cell = range.Cell(1, index + 1);
                cell.Value = arrayCompany[index];
            }
```

This is working, but I guess there is a more clean solution for the problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
cell.InsertData(data: yourEnumerable, transpose: true);
```

Notice the `transpose` parameter, which allows you to insert your values in a row. By default, values of an enumerable would be inserted below each other.

Comment: Transpose is main point to note, I was erroring out for 30mins+ because I missed the transpose and data was getting overwritten.

Comment: @surpavan I updated the answer to highlight the `transpose` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this:

```
worksheet.Cell(x, y).Value = toExport.AsEnumerable();
```

Where my `toExport` variable is a list of objects. It does not only enumerate all properties  to columns, it also inserts every instance in a new row.

This might also work with an array.

Comment: I have tried this solution, but  it's inserting every element in a new row. I want to insert all the elements in one single row which means each element in different column.